# bitcoin cash from fork no longer visible on blockchain.info

Tags: blockchain.info, cash

I had bitcoin before Aug 2017 on Blockchain.info.
After the fork there was a period of time that i could see my BCH balance in Blockhain.info's settings. i can no longer see it. how do i get access to my fork BCH?

Answer (score 0):

> I went to 'settings' then 'addresses', clicked on 'archived
>   addresses', logged out and in again and there they were.

Possible solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoincash/comments/7l2jk2/bch_suddenly_missing_from_blockchaininfo_wallet/